# Get financial reports on Canadian companies

Tags: canada, stock-analysis

I resonantly started investing money in the stock market. I am wondering what is the equivalent to 10k financial reports in Canada. Also where can one download them. For example, in the US you can download 10k reports from www.sec.gov. What would be the Canadian equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

"[www.sedar.com](http://www.sedar.com/homepage_en.htm) is the official site that provides access to most public securities documents and information filed by public companies and investment funds with the Canadian Securities Administrators (CSA) in the SEDAR filing system."

Now, I'm guessing - I think the doc is MDA - Management’s Discussion and Analysis of
Financial Condition and Results of Operations. At least this is what appears listed for many companies.